# Read soap xml with php

Tags: php, xml, soap

Anyone can help on this how I can get the value of callerId from this string?
String is pulled from `php://input` and i need this with just php without soap class and only this one value no loop.
Any idea?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:authorizePlayer xmlns:ns2="http://authorization.wallet.de">
            <authorizationRequest>
                <callerId>mycallerid</callerId>
                <callerPassword>mypassword</callerPassword>
                <playerName>player</playerName>
                <sessionToken>b0f4617bb56f1ed4706908b6ab9a4960</sessionToken>
            </authorizationRequest>
        </ns2:authorizePlayer>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use `DOMDocument`.

Assuming your string is in `$xml` variable, try this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$callerId = $dom->getElementsbyTagName( 'callerId' )->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/HLZmE)**</kbd>

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/it/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the SimpleXMLElement's [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method and register the namespace.

`$element` is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and you can call its [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) method to return the string content:

```
$source = <<<SOURCE
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:authorizePlayer xmlns:ns2="http://authorization.wallet.de">
            <authorizationRequest>
                <callerId>mycallerid</callerId>
                <callerPassword>mypassword</callerPassword>
                <playerName>player</playerName>
                <sessionToken>b0f4617bb56f1ed4706908b6ab9a4960</sessionToken>
            </authorizationRequest>
        </ns2:authorizePlayer>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
SOURCE;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns2', 'http://authorization.wallet.de');
$elements = $xml->xpath('//S:Envelope/S:Body/ns2:authorizePlayer/authorizationRequest/callerId');
$element = $elements[0];
echo $element;
```

Will result in:

> mycallerid